# Background image not displaying and text not in line by image

Tags: html, css, web

I believe that these two are the easiest rookie errors however I am not experienced enough to fix them.

For some reason once I set the background of the full container, the background is in place but it shows the body background behind text, I do not want that. Another problem is the text, I have no idea how to make it aligned on the side of the image just like my website plan.

This is the picture of the problem:
[Click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1GFo.png)

This is what I want it to look like: [Click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJqx0.jpg)

Below is my complete code, I am still learnin so it would be awesome if someone could walk me through what is being changed. Also if you spot bad practise or mistakes then please tell me, It will be very useful to me. Thank you.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,300,300italic,100,100italic,400italic,700italic,900italic);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
header,
article,
nav,
section,
footer,
aside {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Lato', normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: url("../img/background-lighter.png");
}
/* Classes */

.wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
.cell-triple {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cell-double {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cell-single {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.pre-article {
  padding: 70px 50px 50px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.pre-article-image {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 70px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.article1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("../img/background-light.png");
}
.cell-double-article {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000000;
}
.underline {
  border-bottom: 3px double #8c8b8b;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}
.subheading {
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 35px;
}
/* Navigation Bar */

nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000000;
}
nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
}
nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 60%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 130%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: 0.7s;
}
nav .active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
/*  */

h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Streamlite | Index</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

</head>





<body>

  <header id="page-header" class="">

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">ABOUT<a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SERVICES<a></li>
     <li><a href="#">PRICING<a></li>
     <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO<a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CONTACT<a></li>    
    </ul>
   </nav>
   
   <img class="shadow" src="img/pc1.jpg" alt="computer" height="100%" width="100%">
  
  </header>
  
  
  
  
  
  <div id="wrapper" class="">
  
  
  
  
  
   <article id="pre-article" class="pre-article">
   
    <header id="pre-article-header">
     <h1 class="underline"> STREAMLITE SPECIALIZES IN DIGITAL MARKETING SOLUTIONS</h1>
     <h2> We provide a range of online marketing and advertising solutions. </h2>
    </header>  
    
    <section>
   
   
   
   
   
     <section class="cell-triple"> 
     
      <img class="pre-article-image" src="img/icon-bulb.png" alt="computer" height="70" width="70">
     
      <header class="subheading">
       PROFESSIONAL DESIGN
      </header>
     
      We offer only the best responsive websites to our clients. By going with Streamlite, 
      you are guaranteed a modern and sleek bespoke website tailored exactly to your needs.
      
     </section>
     
     
     
     
     
     <section class="cell-triple">
     
      <img class="pre-article-image" src="img/icon-pc.png" alt="computer" height="70" width="70">
     
      <header class="subheading">
       USER FRIENDLY
      </header>
     
      We make sure that your website is easy to use and of exquisite quality. We never fail to neglect the importance of readibility and accessibility.
      We make sure that the content is suited exactly to your traffic's demographics.
      
     </section>
     
     
     
     
     
     <section class="cell-triple"> 
     
      <img class="pre-article-image" src="img/icon-mobile.png" alt="computer" height="70" width="70">
     
      <header class="subheading">
       MOBILE DEVICES
      </header>
     
      We are at a time where your business is no longer stationary and therefore, we utilise modern responsive web development techniques as a standard in order
      to make sure that your company is accessible on devices such as mobile phones and tablets. 
      
     </section>
   
   
   
   
   
    </section>
    
   </article>
   
   
   
   
   
   <article class="article1">  
    
    
     <img class="" src="img/3devices.jpg" alt="computer" height="25%" width="25%">    
    
    
     <section class="cell-double-article"> 
     
     
      <header class="subheading">
       RESPONSIVE WEBSITES
      </header>
      
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet dolor in justo tincidunt convallis.
       Aenean vitae facilisis felis, vitae mollis est. Cras vehicula felis purus, eu semper ante malesuada sed. Donec leo nisi,
       rhoncus eget faucibus eget, porttitor vitae lorem. Aenean venenatis orci non sapien tristique luctus.
       Curabitur at nisl fermentum, sollicitudin mi eu, dignissim tortor. Vivamus sodales.
      
     </section>
     
     
     
     
     
     <section class="cell-double-article"> 
     
     
      <header class="subheading">
       SEO & POSITIONING
      </header>
     
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet dolor in justo tincidunt convallis.
       Aenean vitae facilisis felis, vitae mollis est. Cras vehicula felis purus, eu semper ante malesuada sed. Donec leo nisi,
       rhoncus eget faucibus eget, porttitor vitae lorem. Aenean venenatis orci non sapien tristique luctus.
       Curabitur at nisl fermentum, sollicitudin mi eu, dignissim tortor. Vivamus sodales.
      
      
     </section>
     
     
     
     
     
     <section class="cell-double-article"> 
     
     
      <header class="subheading">
       SOCIAL MEDIA ADVERTISING
      </header>
     
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet dolor in justo tincidunt convallis.
       Aenean vitae facilisis felis, vitae mollis est. Cras vehicula felis purus, eu semper ante malesuada sed. Donec leo nisi,
       rhoncus eget faucibus eget, porttitor vitae lorem. Aenean venenatis orci non sapien tristique luctus.
       Curabitur at nisl fermentum, sollicitudin mi eu, dignissim tortor. Vivamus sodales.
      
      
     </section>
     
     
     
     
     
     <section class="cell-double-article"> 
     
     
      <header class="subheading">
       CONTINUED SUPPORT
      </header>
     
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet dolor in justo tincidunt convallis.
       Aenean vitae facilisis felis, vitae mollis est. Cras vehicula felis purus, eu semper ante malesuada sed. Donec leo nisi,
       rhoncus eget faucibus eget, porttitor vitae lorem. Aenean venenatis orci non sapien tristique luctus.
       Curabitur at nisl fermentum, sollicitudin mi eu, dignissim tortor. Vivamus sodales.
      
     </section>
     
     
     
     
     
   </article>
    

   
  </div>
 
 
 
 
 
  <footer id="footer" class="">
  
  
  
  </footer>
 
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css

```
.article1 img{float:left;}
```

Change the following css in your file

```
.cell-double-article {
  width: 35%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
}
```